# What are the ways or tools available to inspect element in a Mac desktop application

Tags: macos, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, appium-desktop

We have firebug or chropath or inspect element methods to find locators of a web application. Similarly, how to identify element of a Mac desktop application (for example, iTunes desktop app)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UIElementInspector or UI Browser

Comment: Take a look at Apple's Accessibility framework.

Comment: do you mean Accessibility Inspector? How can we use it for generating locators? It provides basic properties of an element such as label, value, coordinates, class, hierarchy of elements etc. But with this, how can we build a locator for an element? 
Consider calculator app as an example. In the Accessibility inspector, targeting the calculator clear (AC) button brings up several details of the AC button such as Label-clear, Type-button, coordinates, then hierarchy of the element and so on. From these details, How do I build the locator for CLR button?

Answer (score 3):

Use Accessibility Inspector,just type in Inspector in the spotlight. So far, its able to get class, text and labels, but not well recognize using it with Appium.  I am hoping for a better more accurate tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyatom (python library for automated testing on MAC).
PyAtom is Python library to fully enable GUI testing of Mac applications via the Apple Accessibility API.

Github link - https://github.com/pyatom/pyatom